# php copy function from one folder to another

Tags: php

Here is my code, what I am trying to do is take the file `post.php` or `$file` from the root of the directory that it is originally from, then put it inside this uniqueID directory, or it should finally arrive in the `$newFolder5` variable to complete. The `$root` in the !copy function is a path pointing to the file inside the current directory, then it should go it the `$newFolder5` directory when the copy function is executed on the page load. Can `$root` or the source of the copy be a string with a directory to the file?

```
<?php
$unique = uniqid();
$root = '/gallry/' . $dir_auth1 . '/'. 'post.php';
$folder = mkdir($unique, 0755); 
$uniqueFolder = '/' . $unique . '/' . 'post.php';
$destination2 = $dir_auth1 . '/'  . $unique . '/' . 'post.php';
$newFolder = '/' . $dir_auth1 . $uniqueFolder;

if (!copy($root, $newFolder)) {
    echo "    status not created."; 

} else {
    echo "Success!";


}
?>
```

I changed `$dir_auth1` to `'aidan'`, since that is the root directory that the `post.php` is in.

In short, what Im trying to do is create a folder/directory with a `uniqid()` and put `post.php` inside of it. Or copy it.

Comment: Why are you using `$folder` in the assignment to `$folder5`? `$folder` is just `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether `mkdir` succeeded, it's not the name of anything.

Comment: You're assigning lots of variables that you never use, making the code very confusing. Can you get rid of all the unnecessary stuff so we can see what you're really doing?

Comment: The second argument to `copy()` must be the filename in the destination directory, not just the directory name.

Comment: @Barmar yes I will revise it

Comment: @Barmar please take a look now.

Comment: The directory you're creating is `$unique`, but then you're trying to copy into `/$dir_auth1/$unique`. That's not the same directory.

Comment: @Barmar I tried that, but it is still returning false on the if statement, so "status not created"

Comment: @Barmar should I remove /$dir_auth1/...

Comment: Your question mentions a `$newFolder5` directory, but it's not in the code after the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating the same directory that you're trying to copy into.

```
$unique = uniqid();
$root = "/gallry/$dir_auth1/post.php";
$uniqueFolder = "/$dir_auth1/$unique";
$destFile = "$uniqueFolder/post.php";
if (mkdir($uniqueFolder)) {
    if (copy($root, $destFile)) {
        echo "Success!";
    } else {
        echo "  status not created";
    }
} else {
    echo "Unable to create folder $uniqueFolder";
}
```

Comment: I removed the strings added replaced them accordingly with the variables.
please take a look, and you didnt define $unique correctly but I fixed it.

`$unique = uniqid();
$root = "/gallry/".$dir_auth1."/post.php";
$uniqueFolder = "/".$dir_auth1."/".$unique;
$destFile = $uniqueFolder."/post.php";
if (mkdir($uniqueFolder)) {
    if (copy($root, $destFile)) {
        echo "Success!";
    } else {
        echo "  status not created";
    }
} else {
    echo "Unable to create folder $uniqueFolder";
}`

Comment: OK, I just find it easier to read by using interpolation rather than concatenation.

Comment: It will work the same either way, that's just coding style.

Comment: Can you double check that and revise your answer if necessary.

Comment: Your code looks equivalent, but I don't see anything wrong with the way I've written it, and I think this is a clearer answer for future readers.  This site is not just for your benefit, it's for everyone.

Comment: I modified the `$uniqueFolder = "/$dir_auth1/$unique";` to `$uniqueFolder = "$unique";` it now changes the output from `"Unable to create folder $uniqueFolder"` to `"  status not created"`

How can I get it to the success output?

Comment: Are you sure you have all the paths correct? Remember, all these pathnames are relative to the server's regular filesystem, not the webserver's document root. Maybe it should be something like `/home/$dir_auth1`?

Comment: Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled, then you should see the specific error from `copy()`.

Comment: I enabled it ` Warning: copy(/gallry/aidan/post.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/thecookie12/public_html/gallry/aidan/index.php on line 59`
gives me that.

Comment: when I revert the code back to what your original answer was it now gives me this  Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /home/thecookie12/public_html/gallry/aidan/index.php on line 58

Comment: Your pathnames are incorrect. Fix them. I don't know the layout of your server, so I can't tell what the correct paths should be.

Comment: `$dir_auth1` looks like this

`$dir_auth = getcwd();
$dir_auth1 = str_replace('/home/thecookie12/public_html/gallry/', '', $dir_auth);`

is that making it conflict with each other?

Comment: I really can't tell from that what you're trying to do. Can you just use absolute pathnames that point to the correct locations?